# SmsManager not working with permissions, no matter what I do

Tags: text, permissions, sms

I've dug through every form, and every answer - nothing works.
I am simply trying to send an SMS message through SmsManager, but it keeps giving the error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10059 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

But my manifest is set properly, I have set permissions for SMS as required:

**manifest Class is:-**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jake.test4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity

            android:exported="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                android:exported="true"
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But still it won't work!

I am literally pulling my eyebrows out trying to get this to work, can someone please tell me what the heck is going on?

**My full Java is here:**

```
 package com.example.jake.test4;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.telephony.SmsManager;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.io.File;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String phoneNumber = new String("5556");
    String  smsBody = new String("You just received an SMS!");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Sending SMS!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                sendSmsByManager();
            }

        });
    }

    public void sendSmsByManager() {
        try {
            // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,
                    null,
                    smsBody,
                    null,
                    null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your sms has failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }
```

Should be as simple as sending a text message.... could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

add this field in your activity

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
```

add in your fab onClickListener

```
 int hasWriteContactsPermission = 0;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
            }
            if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to send sms",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                }
                return;
            }
            // your code to send sms
            //  sendSmsByManager();
```

add this two methods in your activity

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Send SMS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```